# Emergency vehicle lights and siren

Tags: phrase-requests

I need a formal expression to designate the police siren and lights together. In Hungarian they are both called with the same name: ***distinctive signals*** which is different from what we call them when using one of them alone.
Is there a word or expression that I can use in an essay?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I'm unaware of any term that would imply both in the US.  But in the US any time a siren is used flashing lights are used as well, so "siren" would imply the lights were being used too.

Comment: An *informal* British expression is [**blues and twos**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/blues_and_twos).

Comment: The suggested dupe does not answer the question "... police siren and _lights together_.".

Comment: I am less than satisfied with the dupe.